# Chicken with two tracheas

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, slaughter-shochet-shecht, poultry

What would the Halacha be in a case where one slaughtered a chicken and found 2 tracheas from the mouth to the lungs.

If for example only Rov of one of these tracheas were cut would the chicken be Kosher?

I haven't seen any sources in Halacha that discuss such a case.

Comment: Is this a theoretical case or does this happen once in while? (like you find animals with 2 heads once in a while)

Comment: Would it not be a treifa anyway? I guess you can still ask if it's tamei

Comment: It happened once to a friend of mine

Comment: יתר כנטול דמי....

Comment: @sam but is the shchita valid

Comment: If it has a וושט  and that was cut ,it should absolve from tumah since it isn't a neveilah..shechting the kanim is insignificant because the are considered absent ...def an interesting question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT:

After discussing this with a *shochet*, he pointed out that this case is explicit in Shulchan Aruch YD 33:5

> וְכָל שֶׁכֵּן אִם יֵשׁ לוֹ שֵׁנִי וְשָׁטִים אוֹ שְׁנֵי קָנִים, דִּטְרֵפָה (תְּשׁוּבַת הָרא״ש כְּלָל כ׳ סִימָן ט׳)

He pointed out, however, that some geese naturally have a forked trachea (near the bottom, where it enters the lungs), and this is considered "היינו רביתייהו" - that's the way it grows, and is not a טריפה. It also seems that in this case both קנים need to be *shechted*.

There is a general rule in the Halachos of Treifos - כל היתר כנטול דמי - "anything extra is as if it is removed". Basically, if an animal has 5 legs, two of which are connected at the femur, it's as if the entire combination is removed. The removal of the femur of an animal renders it a טריפה. This means that it is prohibited to eat, even if *shechted*, but it is not טמא.

In a case two tracheas or two esophagus', the rule of כל היתר כנטול דמי would apply, so it would be a טריפה.

Comment: Is there a source that discusses this goose phenomenon? The question is apparently actually more relevant than just tahara

Comment: here are the sources that my shochet friend gave me: תבואת שור לג:י, כריתי ופלתי לג:י. There is a discussion in a Sefer called "שחיטה ובדיקה בהלכה", which has a number of ספרי שו׳׳ת that discuss it, but I'm not sure how to post a picture here.