# Are conjoined twin animals inherently treif

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, animals, yoreh-deah, biology

According to Halacha, are animals which are [conjoined twins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjoined_twins) considered injured and therefor inherently treif and non kosher even if from a kosher species? Or no, if they are from a kosher species and Shechita’d properly are they kosher?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/140594/759